# Suppress Xcode adding a new XCTest to every single defined test scheme

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode6.4

I'd like to have Xcode stop adding new unit XCTest unit tests to every test scheme I have defined in my project (workspace). I'm doubtful we have this level of control, but I had to ask:

*Has anyone found a way to do this?*

If you have a lot of tests like I do, you'll find it helpful to partition them into different schemes that you can run at different times.

For example, I have a "Group A" scheme that is meant to run fast. It's meant for developers to use before commits.

We also have a "Group B" and "Group C" scheme; the latter handles loading bulky test data and doing lengthy integration style testing.

Whenever I create a new XCTest, I don't want it added to the three test schemes I have. I'd love to have it just go into one scheme I could move it from or go into no schemes, and let me just opt it into one scheme manually.

Is any more control possible?